# Updating single cells in batch using googlespreadsheet api v4?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

```
$range1 = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$range1->setStartRowIndex(1);
$range1->setEndRowIndex(1);
$range1->setStartColumnIndex(92);
$range1->setEndColumnIndex(92);

$range2 = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$range2->setStartRowIndex(5);
$range2->setEndRowIndex(5);
$range2->setStartColumnIndex(92);
$range2->setEndColumnIndex(92);

$request1 = new Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateCellsRequest();
$request1->setFields('BATCHUPDATE');
$request1->setRange($range1);
$body1 = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$body1->setUpdateCells($request1);



$request2 = new Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateCellsRequest();
$request2->setFields('BATCHUPDATE2');
$request2->setRange($range2);
$body2 = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$body2->setUpdateCells($request2);

$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$batchUpdateRequest->setRequests([$body1, $body2]);
```

The documentation is confusing, because I tried to do several ways, but it didn't work and this way doesn't work either.

https://developers.google.cn/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request?hl=zh-cn#UpdateCellsRequest

There's no other request for updating a single cell, and the way I did it doesn't seem to work.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Do I really have to make several calls instead of batching them? I am trying to update single cells in a batch instead of calling the update call several times.

Answer (score 0):

You can update multiple cells in one [batchRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate), but these cells should constitute a single, contiguous range, since each type of [Request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request) can only be provided once per call, and each [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest) can only be used to update a single range.

Therefore, in order to update multiple non-contiguous ranges you should call `batchUpdate` multiple times.

Apart from this, there are problems with other fields you are providing:

#### RowData:

You are not setting [RowData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#RowData) for your request. Without this you won't be able to set new data to the desired range.

See [setRows](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateCellsRequest.html#_setRows) and the corresponding [Class Google_Service_Sheets_RowData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_RowData.html).

#### fields:

`BATCHUPDATE` and `BATCHUPDATE2` are not valid values for `fields`. `field` should refer instead to one of the fields of [CellData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData) that should be updated (for example, `userEnteredValue`; you can set it to `*` if you want to update all fields).

For more information, see the explanation about `fields` in [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest) and [FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask) format.